# Rundeck and Hipchat Plugin

Tags: plugins, notifications, rundeck, hipchat

I am configuring Rundeck in my work and I want to receive all notifications from jobs via Hipchat. I have found this plugin: https://github.com/hbakkum/rundeck-hipchat-plugin

I copied .jar file in Rundeck libext directory and now I see Hipchat option in Job notification. Despite the fact that I wrote the room ID and I get a token to allow Rundeck sends notifications to this room, nothing happens..

I saw this topic: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/764

Also I am getting this logs:

```
2018-01-31 15:15:12,122 [quartzScheduler_Worker-3] INFO  grails.app.services.rundeck.services.ExecutionUtilService - Execution successful: 13 in project proyecto_prueba
2018-01-31 15:15:12,501 [quartzScheduler_Worker-3] INFO  grails.app.services.rundeck.services.ExecutionService - updated scheduled Execution
2018-01-31 15:15:31,088 [quartzScheduler_Worker-4] ERROR grails.app.services.rundeck.services.PluginService - Notification: configuration was not valid for plugin 'HipChatNotification': apiAuthToken: required
```

is Hipchat plugin working wrong because last update was in 2016 or Am I configuring something wrong?

Thanks beforehand.

Regards,
Mike.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Hipchat API Token has to have next scopes: Send notification y View Room. With these scopes, I have to specify next lines in Rundeck config files:

**configure framework:**
framework.plugin.Notification.HipChatNotification.apiVersion=v2
framework.plugin.Notification.HipChatNotification.apiAuthToken=value

**configure project:**
project.plugin.Notification.HipChatNotification.apiVersion=v2
project.plugin.Notification.HipChatNotification.apiAuthToken=value